# How do I insert array values into a jQuery statement: $(arrayValue).css('width');

Tags: jquery, css, arrays, sizzle

Here is my code:

```
var iconArray = ["icon01", "icon02"];
var iconWidth = $("'." + iconArray[0] + "'").css('width');
```

When I try this code, I get the error message:

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '.icon01' @ jquery-v1-10-0.js:1916

This is evidently a sizzle.error in the jQuery code.

I am wanting to extract the width from the css of a large array of icons to use in a function. The code is successfully converting the text in the () to '.icon01', but it is generating the error mentioned above.

I am relatively new to coding, so please forgive me if my formatting style is not up to par, but please suggest any needed style changes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way to use variable string in selector:

```
var iconWidth = $('.' + iconArray[0]).css('width');
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need this -

```
$('.'+iconArray[0]).css('width');
```